# Vector c++11 и выше

Tags: c++, vector

Вопрос, конечно, безумно глупый, но всё же для меня он статёся...

Могу ли я засовывать элементы в `std::vector<>` с помощью `emplace_back` без использования `reserve`? То есть вопрос именно в том, всегда ли необходимо указывать размер вектора или же есть варианты, чтобы класть данные без указания (чтобы он сам увеличивался при необходимости)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector` использует динамическую память и сам расширяет её по мере необходимости, однако при этом при недостатке зарезервированной памяти не только каждый раз захватывается новая область памяти и освобождается старая, но и вызываются конструкторы и деструкторы элементов (если они определены). Поэтому лучше сделать `reserve` побольше, а потом `shrink_to_fit`.

Comment: http://take.ms/tmL93 пример куска кода, где это испоьзую...
То есть как ни крути лучше всего поставить reserve перед push_back / emplace_back

Comment: ```
for (int i = 0; i < QUEST_REQUIRED_CURRENCY_COUNT; i++) // QUEST_OBJECTIVE_CURRENCY
        packet.Currency.push_back(WorldPackets::Quest::QuestCurrency(quest->RequiredCurrencyCount[i], quest->RequiredCurrencyId[i]));
```

```
class***
std::vector<QuestCurrency> Currency;
***

```
struct QuestCurrency
        {
            QuestCurrency(int32 currencyID = 0, int32 amount = 0) : CurrencyID(currencyID), Amount(amount) { }
            int32 CurrencyID;
            int32 Amount;
        };
```

Comment: Тем более, что размер известен заранее. Перед циклом, конечно.

`emplace_back` оптимальнее, так как в вашем случае элемент сначала создаётся в стеке, а потом копируется на новое место, хотя возможно, оптимизатор это сократит.

Comment: а что произойдёт, если я не буду указывать размер?

Comment: vector в зависимости от реализации может выделять память кусками больше, чем нужно непосредственно сейчас. Когда очередной объект не умещается, будет запрошен больший массив, объекты из старого массива копируются в новый (вызывается size раз конструктор копирования), вызывается size раз деструктор (если бы он был определен) для объектов в старом массиве, освобождается старый массив.
Если указать размер заранее, эта операция будет произведена один раз с пока ещё пустым массивом -- экономия времени и возможно памяти.